# How to create new array with conditionally adding an additional property comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, merge

I have two arrays

```js
lockers: [
  {
    locker_id: 1,
    label: {
      size: 1,
      label: "large"
    }
  },
  {
    locker_id: 2,
    label: {
      size: 3,
      label: "large"
    }
  },
  {
    locker_id: 3,
    label: {
      size: 3,
      label: "large"
    }
  }
]
```

and

```
selectedLockers: [1, 2]
```

Now I need to create a new array by conditionally matching `lockers.id === selectedLocker[id]` and if they match add a new property `color:"yellow"` if does not match `color:"red"`

What I Actually want is:

```js
newLockers: [
  {
    locker_id: 1,
    label: {
      size: 1,
      label: "large",
      color: "yellow"
    }
  },
  {
    locker_id: 2,
    label: {
      size: 3,
      label: "large",
      color: "yellow"
    }
  },
  {
    locker_id: 3,
    label: {
      size: 3,
      label: "large",
      color: "red"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```js
const lockers = [
    { locker_id:1,label:{ size:1,label:"large" } },
    { locker_id:2,label:{ size:3,label:"large" } },
    { locker_id:3,label:{ size:3,label:"large" } }
];
const selectedLockers = [1,2]

const newArray = lockers.map((locker) => {
    if (selectedLockers.includes(locker.locker_id)) {
        locker.label.color = "yellow"
    } else {
        locker.label.color = "red"
    }

    return locker;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a set for lookup:

```
 s = new Set(selectedLockers)
```

then just map over your data:

```
 lockers.map(e => {
   e.label.color = s.has(e.locker_id) ? 'yellow' : 'red';
   return e;
 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your lockers array and for each element check whether that id is present in selectedLockers array. if yes then add the color yellow else red.

```
let newLockers = lockers.map(ele => {
    if (selectedLockers.includes(ele.locker_id)) {
       ele.color = "yellow";  
    } else {
       ele.color = "red";
    }
    return ele;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lockers.map((locker) =>
    selectedLockers.includes(locker.locker_id)
      ? { ...locker, label: { ...locker.label, color: 'yellow' } }
      : { ...locker, label: { ...locker.label, color: 'red' } })
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's a lot more helpful to add some explanation what this code does and how it solves the question. Code only answers are generally not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Map over the `lockers` array to see if its id present in the `selectedLockers` array using `includes` method.

```js
let lockers = [{
    locker_id: 1,
    label: {
        size: 1,
        label: "large"
    }
},
{
    locker_id: 2,
    label: {
        size: 3,
        label: "large"
    }
},
{
    locker_id: 3,
    label: {
        size: 3,
        label: "large"
    }
}
];
let selectedLockers = [1, 2];

const result = lockers.map((locker) => {
  let { label,locker_id } = locker;
  selectedLockers.includes(locker_id) ?
    (label.color = "yellow") :
    (label.color = "red");
  return locker;
});
console.log(result);
```